# how to display a default IMG in PHP if SQL row is null

Tags: php, if-statement, echo

Hello I have a table that stores user profile information as well as their profile picture.

I am currently able to echo the users avatar but my question is how can I echo a default.png avatar if the column is left null. in other words they havent uploaded a profile picture.

```
        <div id="imagePreview" style="background- 
        image: url(avatars/<?php echo 
         $avatar['avatar']; ?>);">
        </div>
```

Comment: `echo !empty( $avatar['avatar'] ) ? $avatar['avatar'] : 'default.jpg'`? or something similar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will you use the avatar more than one in your script? if so, you can create a variable that stores the value or call the default one.
Something like that:

```
<?php
$avatar   =   !empty($avatar['avatar']) ? $avatar['avatar'] : 'default.jpg';
?>
<div id="imagePreview" style="background-image: url(avatars/<?=$avatar;?>);"></div>
```

If you are using it once, you can do it without a variable:

```
<div id="imagePreview" style="background-image: url(avatars/<?=!empty($avatar['avatar']) ? $avatar['avatar'] : 'default.jpg';?>);"></div>
```

Comment: thank you that worked! thank you to everyone with your timely support, I greatly appreciate it! I cannot upvote cause I don't have enough reputation but I sincerely appreciate all your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   <div id="imagePreview" style="background- 
    image: url(avatars/<?php if($avatar['avatar']==""){echo 
   'imagedefault.png';}else{echo $avatar['avatar'];}?>);">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [null coalescing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce) operator:

```php
<div
  id="imagePreview"
  style="background-image: url(avatars/<?= $avatar['avatar'] ?? 'default.png' ?>);">
</div>
```

According to the documentation:

> The expression (expr1) ?? (expr2) evaluates to expr2 if expr1 is null,
> and expr1 otherwise.
>
> In particular, this operator does not emit a notice or warning if the
> left-hand side value does not exist, just like isset(). This is
> especially useful on array keys.

The documentation has an example with:

```php
$action = $_POST['action'] ?? 'default';
```